# HAL links with singular noun instead of plural noun when following rel-links

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas, hal-json

I am using Spring Boot (2.1.1) to automatically create an HAL REST API of my `JpaRepository` interfaces.

For most cases these interfaces are empty, for example:

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Long> {}

public interface ProtocolRepository extends JpaRepository<Protocol, Long> {}
```

A `Project`-entity contains many `Protocol`-entities.
And a `Protocol`-entity has a back-link to its `Project`-entity.

When I visit `http://localhost:8080/admin/protocols/4711` I get the link to its project:

```
...
"project": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/admin/protocols/4711/project"
}
...
```

But when I follow that link all further links are generated faulty:

```
  ...
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/admin/project/1"
    },
    "project": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/admin/project/1"
    }
  ...
  }
  ...
```

The error in the link is that the singular noun `project` is used, instead of the plural form `projects`.

As these links are automatically generated, it is not obvious how this behavior can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

While debugging the Spring internals I figured out that `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` uses an instance of `DefaultSelfLinkProvider` to create the self-links.
When I debugged that class I realized that it does not work correctly when a self link is generated for an object which is proxied by Hibernate.

Therefore I tried to replace the `DefaultSelfLinkProvider` by my own implementation of the `SelfLinkProvider`-interface.

This can be done with an `BeanPostProcessor`:

```
  @Bean
  public BeanPostProcessor entityManagerBeanPostProcessor()
  {
    return new BeanPostProcessor()
    {
      @Override
      public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException
      {
        return bean;
      }

      @Override
      public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException
      {
        if (bean instanceof SelfLinkProvider)
        { return new HibernateSelfLinkProvider((SelfLinkProvider) bean); }
        return bean;
      }
    };
  }
```

And the `HibernateSelfLinkProvider` is a simple wrapper around a `SelfLinkProvider`:

```
public class HibernateSelfLinkProvider implements SelfLinkProvider
{
  private final SelfLinkProvider selfLinkProvider;

  public HibernateSelfLinkProvider(SelfLinkProvider selfLinkProvider)
  {
    this.selfLinkProvider = selfLinkProvider;
  }

  @Override
  public Link createSelfLinkFor(Object instance)
  {
    instance = Hibernate.unproxy(instance);
    return selfLinkProvider.createSelfLinkFor(instance);
  }
}
```

The nice thing about `Hibernate.unproxy()` is that it leaves the given object unchanged, if it is not a proxied object.

With this addition I get the correct link: `"http://localhost:8080/admin/projects/1"`.
But I am not sure if this is the best place to modify the behavior.